# how to display the dataframe in tabular format using php with python code

Tags: php, python

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    $command=escapeshellcmd("D:\Wamp64\www\demo.py");
    $output=shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
<html>
<body>

<script> 
console.log(<?php echo $output ?>);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
dict={1:2,3:4,5:6,7:8}
df=pd.DataFrame(list(dict.items()),columns={'a','b'})
print(df)
```

Output in python terminal is dataframe:

> a  b
>   0  1  2
>   1  3  4
>   2  5  6
>   3  7  8

But executing the same code inside php

My output displays in a web browser looks in sequential order not in a tabular format along with rows and columns:

> a b 0 1 2 1 3 4 2 5 6 3 7 8

Comment: in HTML you have to use `<br>` instead of `\n` OR you have to put text in `<pre> </pre>` to respect `\n`

Comment: html=df.to_html() Python has some inbuilt feature to print in html table i just tried its worked thanks for the constant support